# Linq FirstOrDefault

Tags: linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
    Manager mngr = (from tr in DataContext.Manager
                    where tr.Name = "Jones").FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I check if the query did return 1 record
as I cannot do .Count to get the count.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the FirstOrDefault method. It returns the default for the data type if there are no results. If it's a must that *no more than 1* record passes the query criteria, use SingleOrDefault instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, that is not a valid query.  When you use the query syntax (`from blah in blah ...`), you must have a `select` clause.  It should be more like:

```
var manager =
    (from n in DataContext.Manager
    where n.Name == "Jones"
    select n).FirstOrDefault();
```

To answer your question, calling `FirstOrDefault()` on your query will return the first result of the query or the default value for the type (most likely `null` in this case).  For what you're going for, this won't be an adequate use since the query may contain more than one result.

If you wish to verify that the query only returns a single result, you should use the `SingleOrDefault()` method instead.  It will return either the one item produced by the query, the default value `null` if it was empty or throw an exception if there was more than one item.

If you don't want to throw an exception, it may be easier to just throw the first two results into a list and verify that you only have one.

```
var managers =
    (from m in DataContext.Manager
    where m.Name == "Jones"
    select m).Take(2).ToList();
if (managers.Count == 1)
{
    // success!
    var manager = managers.First();
    // do something with manager
}
else
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: The way I did it was to say if(mngr != null){ .. we know we got at lease 1 record}

Comment: There is also a .Single() that checks you have **exactly** one record

Comment: -1 for suggesting that throwing the results into a list and counting would be an adequate solution.  Doing so on large result sets or where a large table must be traversed to grab all the data would be very bad.  Both First and Single do backend optimizations that can't be replicated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SingleOrDefault` extension method to express that the query only ever should return one result.

```
Manager manager = (from tr in DataContext.Manager 
                   where tr.ID = "2323").SingleOrDefault();
```

However it does not tell you whether you got 0 results or more than 1.

Comment: Please note that `SingleOrDefault` doesn't just *express* that the query should only return one result, but [it also throws an exception if there is more than one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-6.0#:~:text=InvalidOperationException-,The%20input%20sequence%20contains%20more%20than%20one%20element.,-Applies%20to).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the records, count the result of the query *without* FirstOrDefault.

```
var mngr = (from tr in DataContext.Manager
                where tr.ID = "2323")
if(mngr.Count() == 0)
   ....
else
   Manager manager = mngr.First(); //No need for default since we know we have a record.
```

You can still run first or default on the mngr to get the specific manager.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ID for the `where` condition, I think you should've already guaranteed that this query returns only one result.

If your problem is having no result please check the usage of `FirstOrDefault()` from [MSDN title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

```
            int[] numbers = { };
            int first = numbers.FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(first);

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             0
            */
```