# How can get a result of a linq stored procedure into a label which is scalar

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have created an aspx page and i am passing name to a textbox which has to display a message saying that the `user` exists in the database. For this i took a linq and wrote a stored procedure in it(`Select username from logintest where username=@name`).

I want the output of a stored procedure into a label.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your code what do you mean by linq stored procedure?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to accept an answer? Or explain as to why an answer wasn't correct for you situation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want:

```
lblUsername.Text = (Select username from logintest where username=@name).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

And: [Linq FirstOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886796/linq-firstordefault)

For some more inforamtion

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Any.
Code example:

```
logintestDataContext dct = new logintestDataContext();
string userName = "john";

var logintest = (from lt in dct.logintest 
                  where lt.username.Contains(userName)
                  select lt
                 );

lblUserExist.Text = logintest.Any().ToString();
```

Let's explain code:

In logintestDataContext is table logintest

```
logintestDataContext dct = new logintestDataContext();
```

Using Linq, var logintest is filled from table logintest where username is like string userName (in this case john)

```
string userName = "john";
var logintest = (from lt in dct.logintest 
                  where lt.username.Contains(userName)
                  select lt
                 );
```

If there are results in logintest, label text become true. If there are no result label text become false.

```
lblUserExist.Text = logintest.Any().ToString();
```