# How to get first object out from List<Object> using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, c#-4.0

I have below code in c# 4.0.

```
//Dictionary object with Key as string and Value as List of Component type object
Dictionary<String, List<Component>> dic = new Dictionary<String, List<Component>>();

//Here I am trying to do the loping for List<Component>
foreach (List<Component> lstComp in dic.Values.ToList())
{
    // Below I am trying to get first component from the lstComp object.
    // Can we achieve same thing using LINQ?
    // Which one will give more performance as well as good object handling?
    Component depCountry = lstComp[0].ComponentValue("Dep");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886796/linq-firstordefault

Comment: How to check this condition Component depCountry = lstComp[0].ComponentValue("Dep"); getting first is easy how to get Component object from lstComp[0] component, so component is having component

Comment: Also drop the `ToList()` on `Values` it's not needed and requires the creation of an extra object and an enumeration of the entire values collection.

Comment: Bob, what do you suggest instead of using ToList() as I need whole List<Component> object for doing the looping

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try:

```
var firstElement = lstComp.First();
```

You can also use `FirstOrDefault()` just in case `lstComp` does not contain any items.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx

**Edit:**

To get the `Component Value`:

```
var firstElement = lstComp.First().ComponentValue("Dep");
```

This would assume there is an element in `lstComp`.  An alternative and safer way would be...

```
var firstOrDefault = lstComp.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstOrDefault != null) 
{
    var firstComponentValue = firstOrDefault.ComponentValue("Dep");
}
```

Comment: I need that component which is returned from .ComponentValue("Dep") field, that means lstComp[0] has got field which also contain component type of object

Comment: @ManojSingh - you can do lstComp.First().ComponentValue("Depature");

Comment: Wouldn't `lstComp.Select(x => x.ComponentValue("Dep")).FirstOrDefault()` be better? (or even `(from x in lstComp select x.ComponentValue("Dep")).FirstOrDefault()`)

Comment: @BobVale - I wouldn't necessarily say better, there are multiple ways to achieve the same result. However, I personally think the `.Select` with the lambda is not as easy to read as `.FirstOrDefault().`

Comment: Well apart from the fact that firstComponentValue is inaccessible outside the if statement, and you could end up with alot of nesting

Comment: @BobVale - I edited my answer to show a safer practice, you could just use `First` as I also mention. However, If firstOrDefault is `null` you would not want to access `firstComponentValue` .....

Comment: I suppose the main reason is OP asked for a LINQ answer and using the select statement is more LINQ

Comment: @BobVale - .FirstOrDefault is `LINQ` too. Using an unnecessary `Select`, `Lambda`, `from`, `in` clause does not make it `More LINQ`

Comment: The `if` statement is what I was referring to, also the use of the select allows the possibility of creating an anonymous type for a return value if more than one property is needed.

Comment: @BobVale - but the OP wanted the ComponentValue("Dep") value, you can actually see him stating this in the in the comments.  What are you trying to achieve by rambling on here?

Answer (score 7):

`[0]` or `.First()` will give you the same performance whatever happens.
But your `Dictionary` could contains `IEnumerable<Component>` instead of `List<Component>`, and then you cant use the `[]` operator. That is where the difference is huge.

So for your example, it doesn't really matters, but for this code, you have no choice to use First():

```
var dic = new Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Component>>();
foreach (var components in dic.Values)
{
    // you can't use [0] because components is an IEnumerable<Component>
    var firstComponent = components.First(); // be aware that it will throw an exception if components is empty.
    var depCountry = firstComponent.ComponentValue("Dep");
}
```

Comment: Why the ToList() on the Values?

Answer (score 1):

You also can use this:

```
var firstOrDefault = lstComp.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstOrDefault != null) 
{
    //doSmth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all the list at first, then your desired element (say the First in your case):

```
var desiredElementCompoundValueList = new List<YourType>();
dic.Values.ToList().ForEach( elem => 
{
   desiredElementCompoundValue.Add(elem.ComponentValue("Dep"));
});
var x = desiredElementCompoundValueList.FirstOrDefault();
```

To get directly the first element value without a lot of foreach iteration and variable assignment:

```
var desiredCompoundValue = dic.Values.ToList().Select( elem => elem.CompoundValue("Dep")).FirstOrDefault();
```

See the difference between the two approaches: in the first one you get the list through a ForEach, then your element. In the second you can get your value in a straight way.

Same result, different computation ;)

Comment: Both of these answers require an enumeration of the entire collection of values due to the use of `ToList()`

Comment: Sure, I assume it's correct because he's using a Dictionary of List without performace issues. The difference is in the cycle, the second solution is better to me. Modifying his code to fit with a "lighter" one is a loss of time in this case, even if I agree with a better way to store in memory infos. I see at least 2 classes with properties to represent the whole behaviour! Regards.

Comment: Won't the second example fail.  The parameter to `FirstOrDefault` expects a filter function that returns a bool, not a select function

Comment: Ooops, I miss the Select and the first is totally wrong! Thank you, I will fix it!

Comment: Other way round, select before FirstOrDefault

Comment: Return type of FirstOrDefault is single object, not IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

for the linq expression you can use like this :

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>() {1,2,3 };
        var result = (from l in list
                     select l).FirstOrDefault();
```

for the lambda expression you can use like this

List list = new List() { 1, 2, 3 };
            int x = list.FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Component depCountry = lstComp
                       .Select(x => x.ComponentValue("Dep"))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively if you are wanting this for the entire dictionary of values, you can even tie it back to the key

```
var newDictionary = dic.Select(x => new 
            {
               Key = x.Key,
               Value = x.Value.Select( y => 
                      {
                          depCountry = y.ComponentValue("Dep")
                      }).FirstOrDefault()
             }
             .Where(x => x.Value != null)
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value());
```

This will give you a new dictionary.  You can access the values

```
var myTest = newDictionary[key1].depCountry
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of such methods:
`.First .FirstOrDefault .Single .SingleOrDefault`
Choose which suits you best.

Comment: @jle No, it'll return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: it would only contain the first element, but I suppose it would not be the 'first object' per the OP's question

Comment: @jle `Take()` returns an enumeration without actual execution, so you'll still have to use either `.ToList()`, `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault`...etc. to actually execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstObjectsOfValues = (from d in dic select d.Value[0].ComponentValue("Dep"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to it like this:

```
//Dictionary object with Key as string and Value as List of Component type object
Dictionary<String, List<Component>> dic = new Dictionary<String, List<Component>>();

//from each element of the dictionary select first component if any
IEnumerable<Component> components = dic.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Any()).Select(kvp => (kvp.Value.First() as Component).ComponentValue("Dep"));
```

but only if it is sure that list contains only objects of Component class or children

Comment: It can only have Component or its children because you've defined the dictioanry that way!

Comment: Yes I have, in my example. Just feel a need to leave a note, because improper use of `as` operator in linq statement is dangerous and may be cause of application crash. But you're right - it's obvious in this case.