# How do I select a single entity using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, lambda

I want to make a query that returns a specific person (by ID) from person-list (persons).

```
 public Person getThisID(int pID)
 {
     var res = from p in persons
                         where p.pID == pID
                         select p;
     return res;
 }
```

But I got an error about casting problems. I tried to cast `res` to Person but it doesn't work with that. How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? What is the type of the `Persons` list and its elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/215562/11683

Comment: the type is Person
List<Person> persons;

Comment: ok great its worked. i forget () in the end of FirstOrDefault.
thank you all!!!

Answer (score 7):

```
var res= (from p in persons
                         where p.pID == pID
                         select p).SingleOrDefault();
            return res;
```

Comment: Hi , I tried all the versions you gave here. 
with lambda it's worked. but I have to use LINQ.
I still get an error:
'cannot assign method group to an implicity-typed local variable'

Comment: Did you keep the parentheses after `SingleOrDefault`, @user2097810?

Answer (score 6):

`select p;` could potentially return multiple results.

Wrap your query with a .FirstOrDefault();

```
 var res = (from p in persons
            where p.pID==pID
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
 return res;
```

This will return a `null` object if no user is found, or the first user with that Id if many are found.

Alternatively you could use `SingleOrDefault()` which will throw an exception if more than one result is found.

Both the `SingleOrDefault()` and `FirstOrDefault()` methods support passing a filter to them so you could also simplify your query into a 1 line Lambda Statement.

```
return persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.pID == pID);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Persons` is a `Person` collection, `res` is an `IEnumerable<Person>` and not a single person. If you expect only one result, use the [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) method.

Comment: Single would throw an exception if there were no matching elements in the sequence. I'd suggest SingleOrDefault might be better here, allowing for null checking on the result. This obviously assumes the type you are selecting is nullable.

Answer (score 2):

That query will return an `IEnumerable<Person>` and not a single `Person`. That is because the where could return multiple results. Add `FirstOrDefault()` to your result and you're good:

```
public Person getThisID(int pID)
{
    var res = from p in persons where p.pID == pID select p;
    return res.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will return the first instance that meets the condition otherwise the default, most likely `null`.

To shorten things up you could also use a LinQ method with a lambda expression:

```
return persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.pID == pID);
//or...
return persons.Single(p => p.pID == pID);
```

Comment: i think that SingleOrDefault() is more suitable here

Comment: You're right, I prefer that method too. Just giving him the opportunities. :)

Comment: For reference for the OP, SingleOrDefault() will throw an exception if it matches more than one entity whereas FirstOrDefault() will return the first found regardless of the number present. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

if person is `List` then

```
var data = persons.Where( x => x.PID == pid).SingleOrDefault();  
return data
```

Comment: This isn't right. Use of select is wrong and should be `==` not `=`

Comment: You should change `Select` to `Where` as at the moment you are selecting `IEnumerable<bool>` if you use `persons.Select( x => x.PID == pid)`

Answer (score 1):

Using only `FirstOrDefault`:

```
return persons.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.ID == pId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public Person getThisID(int pID)
        {
            Person res= (from p in persons
                         where p.pID==pID
                         select p).First();
            return res;
        }
```

Should work :)

Comment: The type parameter `<Person>` is superfluous.

Comment: This will also throw an exception if there is no matching Person. Either FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault are generally better. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use following snippet

```
 persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == pID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
public Person getThisID(int pID)
{
    return persons.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.pID == pID);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use FirstOrDefault() when returning single value

```
    var res= from p in persons
                 where p.pID==pID
                 select p.FirstOrDefault();
```

[Linq FirstOrDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886796/linq-firstordefault)

Comment: This is a syntax error. You need to wrap the LINQ expression in parentheses then call the extension method.